# Plugging in a second monitor makes windows go behind my panel. How do I debug this?

Tags: multiple-monitors, taskbar, xfce, xubuntu, resizing

On my main screen only, I have an Xfce panel (i.e. my taskbar) at the top of my screen. When I plug in my second monitor, my windows resize and have their tops go **behind** the panel. This persists until I open the 'Panel Preferences' menu.

Unplugging the monitor does not have this effect. Only plugging it in. I think this also has something to do with making Firefox become unresponsive, but I'm unsure and it may be unrelated. Nothing obviously weird has appeared in the task manager.

This issue did not exist in Xubuntu 22.04, which I believe was on Xfce 4.16. I first experienced this issue when I upgraded directly from Xubuntu 22.04 to 23.04. I believe that 23.04 was on Xfce 4.18. It persists on 23.10, which I know to be on Xfce 4.18.

How can I debug this?